# how BroadcastReceive tell Service?

Tags: android, loops, service, handler, broadcastreceiver

on the main activity click a button to start a service

the service will do those jobs:

1,random 10 timestamp for today

2, when each timestamp comes, it will do a task

now i have write the function 1, and when the first timestamp come, i could start the first task

my way is to register a broadcastreceiver for timestamp through alarmmanager, when first broadcast is triggered, then register the second timestamp and so on.....

Here is my question:
when the broadcastreceiver is triggered, how to tell the service to register the next timestamp, then finish the whole job?

Or is that other way to implement of my service?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do like this I think.

I can see at least two shortcomings in your method : 
- the alarmanager will  be too busy
- you can't register a brocast receiver from another broadcast receiver

Another, better way to do it would be to use a handler.postDelayed method :

Your service should ask a handler to come himself back in a few seconds (when you want)

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {    
    //do some treatment based on the action intent
    //first action is used to compute 10 time stamps

    //second action is used to treat task

    //then use a handler to reschedule your service
    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           onStartCommand( <intent for action 2>, flags, startId);
           Log.v( LOG_TAG, "timer sending intent");
        }
    }, delayInMsToNextTask  );
}//met
```

Thus, there is no way for a broadcast receiver.

And I forgot to say that you should register your service for two intent actions in your manifest file.

```
<service android:name="myService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="action1" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="action2" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Also, it could be nice to add a single action but to distinguish what onStartCommand should do using extras in intents with the same name. Then your service would register for a single action in your manifest.

Next time, if you feel your explanations are not so clear, please send some code / pseudo code.

Regards, 
 Stéphane